# Steelseries Arctis Pro Wireless on Stereo very quiet

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control, headset

so I recently have got Linux. I am very new to all of this. I am currently on Kubuntu 20.04 and I have an issue with my headset.

I have done quite a bit of searching and found out that pulseaudio added support for my headset but when I installed it I have 2 options mono and stereo. On stereo everything is extremely quite, even with everything on 100% and the video/ content I am watching on 100%. I have tried the over amplification option to go over 100% but the quality of sound is ruined.

I currently am able to use stereo and mono depending on the application but stereo as I stated before is very quite.

My Steelseries Arctis Pro Wireless is on PC mode with an optical cable connected to my PC although the optical cable doesn't seem to do anything anyways.

If anything needs clarification, feel free to ask. Hope I can get this fixed.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: You do not need the optical cable, audio will be transferred through the USB connected DAC wit high quality. Did the answer below help you to fix the problem?

Answer (score 11):

Gaming headsets like the Arctis Pro Wireless support multiple audio channels, one for voice chat in mono, and the stereo output. The volume for the stereo channel is not controlled when using the Settings/Sound volume setting.
But you can use command line `alsamixer` tool increase the volume for the stereo channel. Open a terminal, launch alsamixer. Press F6 to select the sound card `Arctis Pro Wiresless`. You should see the following screen:

[image]

Select the `PCM 1` channel which controls the stereo volume and raise it to a higher value like 90% (use arrow keys left/right to select, up down to increase decrease volume). You can leave alsamixer pressing the ESC key.
This should fix the problem, but you need to save the setting so it's reapplied after a reboot. This can be achieved by running:

`> sudo alsactl store`

Comment: I love how people just know this stuff lol. Thanks, man :)

Comment: Thanks for tip! Works for Arctis 7 as well.